# Send form content using Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, forms, google-app-engine, cgi

I'm trying to implement a subscribe button on my website that will send whatever the user writes to one of my mails.
I'm trying to write a Python script that would do that.
My website is static and hosted on app engine.

**My form**

```
                <form method="post" action="assets/python/mail.py" class="container 50%">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ton adresse email" /><
                <input type="submit" value="S'inscrire" class="fit special" />  
                </form>
```

**My python script**

```
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import cgi 


def send_approved_mail(sender_address, mail, type):
    # [START send_mail]
    mail.send_mail(sender=sender_address,
                   to="<x@x.com>",
                   subject=type,
                   body=mail)
    # [END send_mail]
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
if form.has_key("email"): 
    mail = form["email"].value
    send_approved_mail('{}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'.format(app_identity.get_application_id()), mail, "client")
```

Two questions:
-Any chance it will work ?

-How do I serve the script with App Engine. What should I do with my app.yaml file ? When I try to use the button it just opens the script as plain text in a new window

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /subscribe/.*
  script: subscribe.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Then rename your Python script to subscribe.py and change its contents to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import mail
from google.appengine.api import app_identity


class Form(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('''
<form method="post" action="/subscribe/send_mail" class="container 50%">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Ton adresse email" />
<input type="submit" value="S'inscrire" class="fit special" />
</form>
''')

class SendMail(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    email = self.request.get('email')
    sender = '{}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com'.format(app_identity.get_application_id())
    mail.send_mail(sender=sender,
                   to="<x@x.com>",
                   subject='Subscribe',
                   body=email)
    self.response.out.write("Sent mail")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/subscribe/form', Form),
  ('/subscribe/send_mail', SendMail),
], debug=True)
```

That should get you started. I hope it helps!

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.
I ended up doing more or so the same as suggested but using Flask instead of webapp2 (I was familiar with Flask)